Timestamp of created_at column is of later data than of updated_at column
We use CreateDateColumn and UpdateDateColumn decorator using typeorm with postgresql as the database. We never update these columns manually but rely on these typeorm decorators for the updation.



created_At
updated_At




2024-07-12 21:49:00.287682
2024-07-12 21:48:52.583741


2024-07-11 15:03:07.320578
2024-07-11 15:03:02.978098



So we have flow where users withdraws money from the platform. Now whenever we get such requests we first deduct money from the users wallet and create an entry in the transaction table. This entry in the transaction table is made in pending state. We call external gateways which in turn interact with banks and provides us the response(Successful or Failure).
The issue i am facing is that this failure/success update is changing the updated_at timestamp and setting it to a value before the transaction insertion
This happens around once or twice in 100000 transactions.

I'll bet the problem is because TypeORM uses the RDBMS GENERATED AS NOW() value for created_At - but uses its own JS new Date() value for updated_At which it'll put into the parameterized query parameter arguments. The updated_At value will therefore predate the created_At value because that JS runs before the SQL INSERT does.
There are a number of solutions:

Set a DEFAULT on updated_At which uses the exact same expression as created_At, and configure TypeORM to exclude both columns from INSERT statements, but to include updated_At in UPDATE statements.

I'm not a TypeORM user so I don't know how easy this is to accomplish.


Use a TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT ON yourTable which will intercept the values of an INSERT statement and set both created_At and updated_At to the same UTC value.

Change updated_At to be a NULLable column, and leave it NULL on INSERT and only set it to a non-NULL value in an UPDATE statement.

Do nothing in the database, but change your application's logic so that it simply ignores updated_At if it predates created_At.



Thanks for the reply Dai.
export function UpdateDateColumn(options?: ColumnOptions): PropertyDecorator {
return Column({
type: "timestamp",
...options,
onUpdate: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",  // Ensures the column is updated with the current timestamp on every update
nullable: false,
});
}
The above is the implementation of UpdateDateColumn decorator. It uses postgresql's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function for updating the date.

Also found this in typeorm change logs.
/now created date and update date columns is set on the database level, not by ORM anymore (e.g. using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default value)/
We use a version after this change happened.

@AashutoshMundra You'll need to use a profiler tool to examine the actual SQL commands that your ORM is sending to Postgres. I cannot help you further.
